# How can I manually reset RX / TX counters in ifconfig output without impacting data delivery?

Tags: networking, centos, ifconfig

CentOS 5.9

I'd like to reset the RX/TX counters in ifconfig output for an interface.  My understanding is that these counters get reset during a reboot but I'd like to avoid rebooting.  Is there another way I can reset that that is non-intrusive to data delivery?

Comment: I've seen this question before on askubuntu, the answer would be the same for you and can be found [here:](http://askubuntu.com/questions/348038/how-to-reset-ifconfig-counters) 
For short unloading / loading kernel module. But that would be somewhat intrusive to your network. So my guess is that you can't.

Comment: @a21 agreed. :-/

Comment: @a21 If you'd like, feel free to post an answer with that information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has already been answered by @SuB on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). I've adapted the answer for CentOS:

Those counters are kept by the kernel, so your answer depends on how your network card driver is built. Two possible choices:

- As a kernel module
- Built into the kernel
  file itself

In second case, you can not reset counters. In the first case, you can do it by unloading the module from the kernel and then loading it back again. If your NIC card uses the e1000 module, use the following commands:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
modprobe -r e1000
modprobe e1000
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Use `ethtool` to find out your NIC module:

```
ethtool -i eth0
```

After "driver" you see your module name:

> driver: e1000
>   version: 7.3.21-k8-NAPI
>   firmware-version:
>   ...

Use `yum` to install `ethtool` as follows:

```
yum install ethtool
```

Comment: You don't need to unload the module.  You can unbind and rebind the driver since ~2005. https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/